# First time Admin Username and Password in nifi

Tags: ldap, apache-nifi, openldap, apache-nifi-registry

I'm new bee and used the below blog to do the nifi https configuration on rhel 6.10. It goes well and I gut i don't know whats the username and password is or where I have mentioned it as per the doc. Any help would be great.

`https://mintopsblog.com/2017/11/01/apache-nifi-configuration/`

Answer (score 1):

The blog post is setting up LDAP integration, so the initial username and password is a user/password from your LDAP.

The post says:

> In the “Initial Admin Identity“, add a known LDAP user which will be
> the NiFi admin at start-up (this can later be changed by policies)

So whatever value you specified for Initial Admin Identity should be the username, and then the password is whatever the password for that user is in LDAP.

Comment: Thanks...Can you tell me where in LDAP do the password reside for that user? If its mentioned in the doc can you please redirect me there?

Comment: Depends on which LDAP implementation you are using, not related to nifi in any way.

Comment: I didn't do anything outside the configuration mentioned in the blog. So, which one is the password as per it? @Bryan. Please help me with it

Comment: The blog assumes you setup your own LDAP, under login-identity provider section it says... "You would then need to edit the file depending on your LDAP settings. Here is an example of how I configured it with my own LDAP server (you would need a LDAP user that has read permissions on the Domain Forest):"

Comment: So, do I need to configure LDAP separately to get password? If yes, can you help me with it? @Bryan. Or can you provide me some other documentation i.e simple enough to follow which gives me nifi with authentication of username/password? Please

Comment: This blog shows how to use Apache Directory Studio as an LDAP server... https://pierrevillard.com/2017/01/24/integration-of-nifi-with-ldap/